# Function takes in a Ticker Symbol of a company and loads a dataframe. Sometimes the Ticker is delisted or does not work. How do I eliminate?

Tags: python, pandas, return, jupyter, yfinance

I made a function that takes in a ticker symbol and loads a data frame with the corresponding chart values for that company, I want to read the output that it gives and remove those tickers from the list that I have no data for. How should I do this?

Python Code:

```
#Get data Command
def get_data(tick,per,inter):
    data = yf.download(tickers=tick, period=per, interval=inter)
#Loading Ticker Symbols
df_tick = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\paliw\2000_tick.xlsx')
print (df_tick)
#Creating a list of Ticks
ticklist = []
for i in df_tick[['Symbol']]:
    ticklist = df_tick[i]

for i in ticklist:
    get_data(i,'1y','1d')
```

When I run my command then sometimes I get a failed download, I want to remove these ticker value from the list.

[This is the output I am getting, I want to take all the values that say Failed Download and remove their ticker symbols from the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s48DA.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What errors are you getting?  What happens when you run the code?

Comment: Neither `NTT` nor `EON` are not present in Yahoo finance. Where did you get your ticker list from?

Comment: I compiled a list myself from a third party website, it has close to 2000 ticker symbols and stored those values into a excel file since I was not able to get beautiful soup to scrape data off of yahoo finance (P.S. - I am very new to these libraries, sorry for any stupid questions or code). I have attached a png of the output messages I am getting from running the code, there are a lot of ticker symbols where it says "Failed Download" and lists the ticker whose download was incorrect. I want to get rid of these ticker Symbols and that is where I am facing a problem.